# Problems with header files on atom

Tags: c++, header, atom-editor

I am having some problems while compiling c++ on Atom. I had been getting an error trying to link a header file with my source. And without changing anything, it suddenly ran properly after one day. Now, I am trying to compile two source files and a header one and I am getting an error saying class not declared in this scope. These are my files:

Source1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mine.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
  Perfect parfait ;
  parfait.opa();
  parfait.part();

  return 0;
}
```

Source 2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mine.h"
using namespace std;

void Perfect::opa() {
  cout << "Numerai" << endl;
}

int Perfect::part() {
  int i = 2+4;
  return i;
}
```

Header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef FILE_H_
#define FILE_H_

class Perfect {
public:
  opa();
  part();
};
    #endif
```

Comment: There is no definition of class `Perfect` anywhere in the code you're showing. Perhaps you might want to read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) to get a firmer grasp on the basics of the language.

Comment: Sorry, I was making changes and posted the wrong file! I am pretty sure the code is correct. I think there is something wrong with Atom compiler. Any suggestions?

Comment: what command are you using to compile? And is that the header file? Cause you are missing the declaration of class `Perfect`.

Comment: @user9851117 First off, Atom is a text editor/IDE, not a compiler. Second, can you please [edit] your question to post the correct code? And while compiler bugs are always possible, I doubt that's the case here. You probably have something wrong in your code. We can't tell for sure until you post a [mcve], though.

Comment: I edited it to the correct files. Do you see anything wrong now?

Comment: What Atom packages are you using to "compile" your code? As mentioned, Atom is **not** a compiler, it's just an editor. Perhaps you mean that you're using some linter or static code checker package and that the tool cannot find your header file?

Comment: No, I don't, I use MinGW. Atom probably has nothing to do with it (sorry I'm new to this!) , as I ran it from command prompt and got the same mistake. Any ideas what is happening? Do you think there is something wrong with the compiler?